# How parse data from local storage in the typescript file?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a user-stored array in the local storage, each with login, password, role and email. This is data about registered users. I need to write this array into a variable in the typescript.I created a variable existingUsers

```
public existingUsers: { login: string, password: string, email: string, role: string } [];
```

and transferred json from local storage to it

```
logInUser() {
    this.existingUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('allUsers'));
    console.log(this.existingUsers[0].login);
}
```

but after that all the properties existingUsers, such as login of password, are undefined. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

```
let existingUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('allUsers'));
if (existingUsers == null) {
  existingUsers = [];
}

let currentUser;
if (this.password === this.confirmPassword) {
  currentUser = {
    'login': this.login,
    'email': this.email,
    'role': this.role,
    'password': this.password,
  };
  currentUser = JSON.stringify(currentUser);
  localStorage.setItem('user', 'user');
  // Save allEntries back to local storage
  existingUsers.push(currentUser);
  localStorage.setItem('allUsers', JSON.stringify(existingUsers));
```

Comment: It's probably an issue when you initialise `existingUsers`. Can you please add the code where you set the `existingUsers`?

Comment: As you are checking the console already, you may want to log ```localStorage.getItem('allUsers')``` too.

Comment: I'm add the code where I set the existingUsers

Comment: It may help to add some console logs around this as well. As @tevemadar mentioned, it would be good to log the entire `this.existingUsers` array to see what values have been stored

Comment: The console displays data as `["{"login":"sss","email":"cdd@er","role":"Dentist","password":"12"}"]`

Comment: Your ```this.existingUsers``` ends up being an array of **strings**, because of the ```currentUser = JSON.stringify(currentUser);```. That is what you see in the log too, that is not an object, but a string (the ```["{...}"]```)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`this.existingUsers`** is an object not an array, you need to access without using **`index`**

```
logInUser() {
    this.existingUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('allUsers'));
    console.log(this.existingUsers.login);
}
```

**EDIT**

The problem lies here,

```
 currentUser = JSON.stringify(currentUser);
  localStorage.setItem('user', 'user');
  // Save allEntries back to local storage
  existingUsers.push(currentUser);
```

you are stringifying the user before pushing to the array, do it as follows,

```
  const User = JSON.stringify(currentUser);
  localStorage.setItem('user', User); //use different object
  // Save allEntries back to local storage
  existingUsers.push(currentUser);
```

now you can get **`existingUsers`**